# Многопоточность. Проблемы с пониманием mutex и lock_guard

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

UPD: удалил вторую часть вопроса, оставил чисто мьютекс и лок-гард.

Осваиваю многопоточность, но что-то, видимо, я понимаю не так.
Далее на примере кода опишу, как я понимаю, он должен работать, а вы укажите, мне, пожалуйста, что я не учел, ибо, исходя из моей логики, все должно работать.

Мне нужно создать словарь, разделенный на несколько частей для того, чтоб иметь возможность одновременно получать доступ к разным диапазонам, но не получать одновременного доступа к одному, я выбираю в качестве полей класса вектор словарей и вектор мьютексов. Так же я добавляю в поля класса две переменные, в которых будет храниться размер, на который делится словарь, и размер одной части словаря. Чтоб иметь к ним доступ в любом месте кода.

У меня есть вспомогательная функция, которая переводит из знакового числа в беззнаковое.

В конструкторе я инициализирую оба вектора, присваиваю значение размеру и вычисляю размер одной секции.

В операторе квадратных скобок я вычисляю, к какой секции относится ключ, и возвращаю ссылку на значение этого ключа через вектор(секция)(ключ) и лок_гард мьютекса из соответствующей секции вектора мьютексов, чтоб залочить секцию для изменения другим потоком.

И вот здесь возникает проблема. Судя по результатам теста, секция не лочится.

Собственно, код:

```
#include "test_runner.h"
#include "profile.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
size_t Unsign(T position) {
    size_t pos = position - numeric_limits<T>::min();
    return pos;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
void UpdateMap(mutex& mut, map<K, V>& maps, map<K, V>& result) {
    lock_guard<mutex> l(mut);
    result.insert(maps.begin(), maps.end());
}

template <typename K, typename V>
class ConcurrentMap {
public:
  static_assert(is_integral_v<K>, "ConcurrentMap supports only integer keys");

  struct Access {
    V& ref_to_value;
    lock_guard<mutex> l;
  };

  explicit ConcurrentMap(size_t bucket_count) : size_(bucket_count), mutexs(bucket_count), maps(bucket_count) {
      size_of_one = Unsign(numeric_limits<K>::max()) / size_;
  }

  Access operator[](const K& key) {
      size_t position = Unsign(key) / size_of_one;
      return { maps[position][key], lock_guard(mutexs[position]) };
  }

  map<K, V> BuildOrdinaryMap() {
      map<K, V> result;

      vector<future<void>> f;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < maps.size(); i++) {
          f.push_back(async(UpdateMap, ref(mutexs[i]), ref(maps[i]), ref(result)));
      }
      for (auto& i : f) {
          i.get();
      }

      return result;
  }

private:
    size_t size_ = 1;
    size_t size_of_one;
    vector<mutex> mutexs;
    vector<map<K, V>> maps;
};

void RunConcurrentUpdates(
    ConcurrentMap<int, int>& cm, size_t thread_count, int key_count
) {
  auto kernel = [&cm, key_count](int seed) {
    vector<int> updates(key_count);
    iota(begin(updates), end(updates), -key_count / 2);
    shuffle(begin(updates), end(updates), default_random_engine(seed));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      for (auto key : updates) {
        cm[key].ref_to_value++;
      }
    }
  };

  vector<future<void>> futures;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) {
    futures.push_back(async(kernel, i));
  }
}

void TestConcurrentUpdate() {
  const size_t thread_count = 3;
  const size_t key_count = 50000;

  ConcurrentMap<int, int> cm(thread_count);
  RunConcurrentUpdates(cm, thread_count, key_count);

  const auto result = cm.BuildOrdinaryMap();
  ASSERT_EQUAL(result.size(), key_count);
  for (auto& [k, v] : result) {
    AssertEqual(v, 6, "Key = " + to_string(k));
  }
}

int main() {
  TestRunner tr;
  RUN_TEST(tr, TestConcurrentUpdate);
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы используете `std::ref`? Он возвращает инстанс шаблона`std::reference_wrapper`, а не сам тип (Вторая проблема). А вы принимаете непосредственно map. Конечно он не сможет вывести типы ключей и значений. И где результаты теста?

Comment: По первой проблеме: В тест `TestConcurrentUpdate` вы вызываете функцию `RunConcurrentUpdates` без ожидания завершения обновления словарей. После вызова этой функции вы вызываете `BuildOrdinaryMap`, которая также лочит каждый словарь отдельно. Но функции `RunConcurrentUpdates` в цикле вы инкрементируете значения из многопоточного словаря, при каждом инкременте лочит словарь. Здесь все вроде нормально. Но результат, возможно, каждый раз будет разный. Так как обновление словарей может закончиться позже, чем строительство единого словаря. Не очень понятна цель сего действа вообще.

Comment: Вам стоит разделить вопрос на два отдельных конкретных вопроса сократив код до минимального.

Comment: @VTT, согласен. Доберусь до компа, попробую исправить.

Comment: @MrBin ref я использую потому, что без этой обертки (как я понял) в функцию передадутся копии аргументов, а не сами аргументы. Что касается второго замечания, так в конце выполнения функции `RunConcurrentUpdates` вызывается деструктор вектора фьючеров, что приводит к завершению всех потоков, разве нет?

Comment: Я уже описал причину: хоть `std::referenve_wrapper` имеет неявный оператор преобразования в тип `T`, но template deduction не использует implicit conversion для типа. Вам нужно вручную получить объект через `get()`. Но даже тогда вам не нужна функция `std::ref`, так как оператор [] вектора уже возвращает ссылку на объект.

Comment: Да, есть такое поведения у `std::future` из под `std::async`. Сам не знал.

Comment: @MrBin удалил рефы, ничего не изменилось, те же ошибки выдало

Comment: В комментариях слишком долго описывать. Если говорить простым языком, то ссылки - это указатели с некоторыми ограничениями. Если замените функцию так, чтоб она принимала указатели, то все должео работать.

Comment: @MrBin надо было шаблонные параметры у функции указать. Реф ни при чем. `f.push_back(async(UpdateMap<K, V>, ref(mutexs.at(i)), ref(maps.at(i)), ref(result)))` - такая формулировка принялась компилятором без проблем

Comment: @ArMANIAK У вас проблема как раз таки в `ref`: передавая в шаблон объекты `::std::reference_wrapper` параметры шаблона не могут быть ведены. Используя `ref`, а потом заставляя аргументы неявно преобразовываться обратно в обычную ссылку вы делаете бесполезные действия.